# getting error unhashable type list in my python code

Tags: python

I'm getting this error when I run my python code, but I'm kind of learning my way around python and I'm having trouble decipher what's wrong with the code. I'm getting "unhashable type: list" error. Error is showing on line 54, and 35. I wonder if I'm missing some import. I've checked the code, but I don't see the error

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import string

def rotate(str, n):
    inverted = ''
    for i in str:
        #calculating starting point in ascii
        if i.isupper():
            start = ord('A')
        else:
            start = ord('a')
        d = ord(i) - start
        j = chr((d + n) % 26 + start)
        #calculating starting point in ascii(d + n) + start
        inverted += j

    return inverted


'''
    making a dictionary out of a file containing all words
'''
def make_dictionary():
    filename = "/home/jorge/words.txt"
    fin = open(filename, 'r')
    dic = dict()
    for line in fin:
    line = line.split()
    dic[line] = line
    return dic



'''
    function that rotates a word and find other words
'''
def find_word(word):
    rotated_words = dict() #dictionary for storing rotated words
    for i in range(1, 14):
    rotated = rotate(word, i)
    if rotated in dic:
        print word, rotated, i      



if __name__ == "__main__":

    words = make_dictionary()
    for w in words:
    find_word(w)
```

I wonder if I'm missing some imports?

Comment: Lists can't be used as keys for dicts, as they mutable, what are you trying to use as a key for your dict?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the full error traceback.

Comment: *"I wonder if I'm missing some imports?"* - what about the error message suggested that that would be the case?

Answer (score 3):

For example:

```
line = line.split()
dic[line] = line
```

`line` is a `list` after the `split` and, as the error message tells you, lists aren't hashable; dictionary keys must be hashable. The minimal fix is to use an (immutable, hashable) `tuple` instead:

```
dic[tuple(line)] = line
```

Note that dictionary *values* can be lists, the restriction applies only to *keys*.

Answer (score 1):

This makes `line` a list:

```
line = line.split()
```

`dict` keys need to be [hashable](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-hashable), and `lists` are not hashable:

```
dic[line] = line
```

---

In your code it's not clear you need a dict. A set of words would suffice:

```
def make_set():
    filename = "/home/jorge/words.txt"
    result = set()
    with open(filename, 'r') as fin:
        for line in fin:
            for word in line.split():
                result.add(word)
    return result
```

Using a set will remove duplicate words.